# Exceptions when using web service with EF

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework-4, web

I'm getting this exception when calling my web service. I'm using EF in my service and trying to return a POCO class created by EF. Any ideas??

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. --->          System.InvalidOperationException: There
>   was an error generating the XML document. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Job_3C04107CB03F22888B19EF7537A795C816D03441852DC37A42729E7542384BBE
>   was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to
>   specify types that are not known statically.   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write2_Job(String
>   n, String ns, Job o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write9_GetJobByNumberResponse(Object[]
>   p)   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer13.Serialize(Object
>   objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues, Stream outputStream)   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()   --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

ok i found a post that mentioned setting the ProxyCreationEnabled property to false;  Ive done this and now it works fine.  Whats the knock on effect of setting this property to false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to disable lazy loading and proxy creation on the EF context otherwise your POCO as the exception states is actually a `DynamicProxy` which cannot be serialised.

[This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/05/04/entity-framework-4-wcf-amp-lazy-loading-tip.aspx) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125135244/http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/05/04/entity-framework-4-wcf-amp-lazy-loading-tip.aspx)) will provide a little more info.

Comment: i set the ProxyCreationEnabled property to false, Ive not changed LazyLoadingEnabled.  Whats the knock on effect of setting ProxyCreationEnabled  to false?

Comment: It means you won't get Lazy loading but if you think about this in the context of a WCF Service that's what you want.  Once the object has been deserialised at the client and the WCF channel has been closed there's no way it can lazy load anything.